# progressBar and refresh webview combination android

Tags: android, webview, runnable

EDIT:
I am using a ProgressBar for a Webview that works fine. Now I want to refresh my Webview, which also works. When I am trying to combine them, the Spinner doesn't end at all. This is my code:

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            //Toast.makeText(WebcamsScreen.this,"in runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            doRefreshingStuff(id);
            WebcamsScreen.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 20000);            
        }

    };



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //initialitions 

        doRefreshingStuff(id);
        this.mHandler = new Handler();

        this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,20000);

        doRefreshingStuff(id);
    }
public void doRefreshingStuff(String id){

                setContentView(R.layout.web4);

                webView7 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_4_1);

                webView7.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView7.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebcamsScreen.this, "example", "...");
                url="my url";
webView7.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url1) {              
                    view.loadUrl(url1);
                    return true;
                }


              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url1) {
                    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
              webView7.loadUrl(url);
```

what must I change?

Comment: You do _not_ want to be running `onCreate` yourself. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to call onCreate over and over again?

Comment: I have set a progressBar for a webview. and with the above code it doesn't working. I will edit my post in a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are refreshing your WebView every 20 seconds and popping up a new progress dialog when you do. Your code assumes that the old progress dialog has already been dismissed. If it hasn't, then the progress dialog just became orphaned and will remain on display forever. You can probably fix this by inserting this code:

```
if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
    progressBar.dismiss();
}
```

just before the line `progressBar = ...`.

But I wouldn't fix your code that way. You are doing a huge amount of work that you don't need to do. (For instance, you don't need to reload the same content view.) Here's my revised version:

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doRefreshingStuff(id);
        mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 20000);
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initialitions 

    setContentView(R.layout.web4);
    webView7 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_4_1);
    webView7.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView7.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView7.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (!mProgressBar.isShowing()) {
                mProgressBar.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url1) {
            if (mProgressBar.isShowing()) {
                mProgressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressBar.setTitle("example");
    mProgressBar.setMessage("...");

    mHandler = new Handler();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.post(m_Runnable);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(m_Runnable);
}

public void doRefreshingStuff(String id) {
    url="my url";
    webView7.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Note that I moved the starting of the page loading loop to `onResume()` and kill the looping in `onPause()`. You may want slightly different logic, but you should definitely stop looping somehow when your activity pauses or finishes.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it. I get this error: Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onResume(). If you can help me, you will be my hero.

Comment: i also get this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity  android.app.SuperNotCalledException: <...>Activity did not call through to <...>super.onResume()

Comment: @qwerty_gr - Sorry. I neglected to call through to `super` in `onPause()` and `onResume()`. I updated the code to show what needs to be done.