# How to make progress bar with percentage when refreshing the url (Android App)

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar

Firstly sorry for my broken English.
By the way, i now stuck to do progress bar with percentage when i want to refresh the URL address using my app. I try using progressBar in my code, but it will never stop even the address completely refresh. So, do you have any solution for me? I already search for this case, but did not working for me. Maybe I put in wrong way or else. Do help me. I'm beginner. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    if (progress == 100) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
 }
});
```

and your webview client will be...

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: i try first okay sud.

Comment: Sud, actually i already have function to refresh the url... but now, i need to add progressBar with percentage.. before this i using toast.. but someone ask me to change it into something like loading that have percentage.. do you understand what i mean? he. sorry for my english..

Comment: ok for that for refreshing part follow the [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812077/progressbar-and-refresh-webview-combination-android)

Comment: else if (clickCount == 1) {
                        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("GrasslandPref", 0);
                        String url = pref.getString("URL", "http://localhost:8080");
                        myWebView.loadUrl(url);

                        Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Refreshing.......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                        if (duration == 0)
                            duration = 1;
                    }

Comment: that is my code for referesh part.. do you have an idea how to implement progressBar with percentage to replace the toast?

Comment: toast message is not a good idea for showing  progress of url loading... you must use progress bar for this. see example given by me to achieve that

Comment: sud, i can't share bcoz my reputation not good enough to post it... ya.... thats why i want to change it. but its quite dizzy to implement this code inside my long code... aishhhh.....